Vertical spacing between two Equation Blocks
Please consider the following LaTex code:
\begin{align*}
a1 &= 3 \\
a2 &= 4
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a3 &= 3 \\
a4 &= 4
\end{align*}

When LaTex generates the image, there is a blank line after the equation  a2 = 4. Is there a way to suppress this blank like?

Why are you using two aligns in the first place? You should use a single construction.

@daleif With a single construction, all the equations do not fit on one line. That is, some have a lot on the left hand side and some have a lot on the right hand side.

That is when you use gather* with two aligned inside, like mico showed their answer. Having several math contructions in a row like that should ring a bell that this is not a good idea.


Is there a way to suppress this blank li[n]e?

I will assume that you have two separate align-type structures because the alignment points within each structure needn't be the same across structures. (If, to the contrary, the alignment points should be common across the structures as well, you should almost certainly be using a single align* environment instead of two separate align* environments.)
If my assumption is correct, I suggest you (a) switch from align* to aligned environments and (b) encase the aligned environments in a gather* environment.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable documen class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*', 'gather*', and 'aligned' environments
\setlength\textwidth{3cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a1 &= 1 \\
a2 &= 2
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
a3 &= 3456 \\
a4 &= 4567
\end{align*}
vs.
\begin{gather*}
\begin{aligned}
a1 &= 1 \\
a2 &= 2
\end{aligned} \\ % <-- "\\" is new
\begin{aligned}
a3 &= 3456 \\
a4 &= 4567
\end{aligned}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}

